# How to set backgroundcolor of different panel in one tag?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have chosed jQuery ui tags in my project. And they are named by tabs1 and tabs2.

I can use ui-tabs-panel{background:lightyellow;} to set background, and the background of tabs1 and tabs2 are both lightyellow;Here is css code:

```
<style>
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel{background: lightyellow;}
</style>
```

Here is html code:

```
<div id="tabs" class="div2">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#tabs1" style="font-size:10px"></a></li>
 <li><a href="#tabs2" style="font-size:10px"></a></li>
 </ul>
  <div id="tabs1" style="height:60%" >
    sdf
  </div>
  <div id="tabs2" style="height:60%">
    Morbi 
  </div>
</div>
```

But I want background of tabs1 is lightyellow, and tabs2's blue. 
I have tried:

```
<div id="tabs1" style="height:60%;background:lightyellow;">
sdf
</div>
<div id="tabs2" style="height:60%;background:blue;">
Morbi
</div>
```

But it works failed.

I don't know how to set css, Who can help me?

Comment: setting inline styles like you did in should work. But don't forget to delete <style>
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel{background: lightyellow;}
</style> because this will override your inline styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

used `!important`

```
<style>
  .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel{background: lightyellow;!important}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

To overrule your background you can use:

```
<div id="tabs1" style="height:60%;background:lightyellow !important;">
```

Hope it helped